# How to add class for two labels with the same "for" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have something like accordion with left side labels navigation, and inner (inside accord section) labels like "next/prev". So the question how to check if there are two the same labels with attr "for" and add class to them?

```css
input {
display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
color: red;
}

input + section {
display: none
}

input:checked + section {
display: block
}

label {
display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label for="check">Label #1</label>
<label for="check2">Label #2</label>
<label for="check3">Label #3</label>
<label for="check4">Label #4</label>

<div>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="check"> 
<section>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae graeci vidisse et his, et vis quod appetere vulputate, eius verear habemus usu ne. Et usu senserit mediocrem imperdiet, habeo fugit paulo mel at. Velit minimum te qui. Sed te pertinacia eloquentiam, ad modus ponderum luptatum vel, vidisse accommodare id sit
<div><label for="check2">Next #2</label></div>
</section>
  
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="check2"> 
<section>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae graeci vidisse et his, et vis quod appetere vulputate, eius verear habemus usu ne. Et usu senserit mediocrem imperdiet, habeo fugit paulo mel at. Velit minimum te qui. Sed te pertinacia eloquentiam, ad modus ponderum luptatum vel, vidisse accommodare id sit

  <div><label for="check">Prev #1</label>
  <label for="check3">Next #3</label>
    </div>
</section>
  
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="check3"> 
<section>
Mel no erat platonem. Ius ad veritus minimum molestiae, ea blandit adolescens vix. Impetus epicuri ocurreret usu in, id aeterno fastidii molestiae his. Eruditi nonumes vel cu, has feugait ancillae efficiendi ex, cu vel augue tacimates. Augue mnesarchum et mei.

  <div><label for="check3">Prev #3</label> <label for="check4">Next #4</label></div>
</section>
  
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="check4"> 
<section>
Odio facilisis persequeris eu sed, in sea oblique labores. Ei vel utamur menandri, paulo omnium delectus vix id. Pri choro impetus persecuti eu. Est id illud luptatum dissentiunt. Vim id nemore aliquip, sea eligendi deseruisse ea. Quot elitr et has, deleniti oportere et nec, an molestiae adipiscing eos.
<div><label for="check3">Prev #3</label><label for="check">Next #1</label></div>
</section>



</div>
```

Comment: I don't really quite get what you mean. Can you also provide some code?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have a form control there, so any label element would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select all labels with the same input id and add your class:

```
var id = "check",
    label = $('label[for="' + id + '"]');

label.addClass('your-class');
```

This will help you:

```
$('.btn-lbl').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('for');
    $('.how-it-works--label[for="' + id + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Yes sure, you either have to replace the id variable or to define it. See edit.

Comment: ok. lets use link where I'm working on: http://goldforgame.com/catalog/money/perfect_world_international/
left side are labels, right side is the content with the labels. When I click labels from right side, the left side appropriative label should trigger click.

Comment: Oh!!! Perfect! Thanks! You saved the very important thing for everyone  - time. Cheers!

Comment: But as @Quentin already mentioned, you may want to use some button tag, since this is an inappropriate usage of the label tag.

Comment: Made smt like this in the end to do the rest: 
$('.how-it-works--label[for="' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
You can see the result on link from above.